# Exact model converging on keras-tf but not on keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on predicting the [EWMA (exponential weighted moving average) formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) on a time series using a simple RNN. Already posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348091/predict-exponential-weighted-average-using-a-simple-rnn).

While the model converges beautifully using keras-tf (from tensorflow import keras), the exact same code doesn't work using native keras (import keras).

Converging model code (keras-tf):

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

def run_avg(signal, alpha=0.2):
    avg_signal = []
    avg = np.mean(signal)
    for i, sample in enumerate(signal):
        if np.isnan(sample) or sample == 0:
            sample = avg
        avg = (1 - alpha) * avg + alpha * sample
        avg_signal.append(avg)
    return np.array(avg_signal)

def train():
    x = np.random.rand(3000)
    y = run_avg(x)
    x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1, 1))
    y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))

    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype='float32')
    rnn_layer = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, stateful=True, activation=None, name='rnn_layer_1')(input_layer)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=rnn_layer)

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1), loss='mse')
    model.summary()

    print(model.get_layer('rnn_layer_1').get_weights())
    model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=1, epochs=10, shuffle=False)
    print(model.get_layer('rnn_layer_1').get_weights())

train()
```

Non-converging model code:

```
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN, Input
from keras.optimizers import SGD

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

def run_avg(signal, alpha=0.2):
    avg_signal = []
    avg = np.mean(signal)
    for i, sample in enumerate(signal):
        if np.isnan(sample) or sample == 0:
            sample = avg
        avg = (1 - alpha) * avg + alpha * sample
        avg_signal.append(avg)
    return np.array(avg_signal)

def train():
    x = np.random.rand(3000)
    y = run_avg(x)
    x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1, 1))
    y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))

    input_layer = Input(batch_shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype='float32')
    rnn_layer = SimpleRNN(1, stateful=True, activation=None, name='rnn_layer_1')(input_layer)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=rnn_layer)


    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), loss='mse')
    model.summary()

    print(model.get_layer('rnn_layer_1').get_weights())
    model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=1, epochs=10, shuffle=False)
    print(model.get_layer('rnn_layer_1').get_weights())

train()
```

While in the tf-keras converging model, the loss minimizes and weights approximate nicely the EWMA formula, in the non-converging model, the loss explodes to nan. The only difference as far as I can tell is the way I import the classes.

I used the same random seed for both implementations. I am working on a Windows pc, Anaconda environment with keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow version 1.13.1 (which includes keras in version 2.2.4-tf).

Any insights on this?

Comment: Maybe you can check if the classes are the same by printing them. If they differ try to find difference in the two. That would be a quick and dirty way to investigate it.

Comment: The classes are not exactly the same since one is the internal implementation of the keras API within tensorflow (maintained by google as far as i know), it is implemented specifically for tensorflow. 
the second "native" keras is a framework agnostic api that can also work with theano. they both implement the same objects and API and suppose to give the same results, but apparently this is not the case...

Comment: Interestingly, this happens only when the argument `stateful` of `SimpleRNN` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of difference (1 liner) in implementation of SimpleRNN, between [TF Keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1364-L1375) and [Native Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1082-L1091).

The Line mentioned below is implemented in TF Keras and is not implemented in Keras.

```
self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=3)]
```

One case of this difference is that mentioned by you above.

I want to demonstrate similar case, using `Sequential` class of Keras.

Below code works fine for TF Keras:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential as Sequential

np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility

def run_avg(signal, alpha=0.2):
    avg_signal = []
    avg = np.mean(signal)
    for i, sample in enumerate(signal):
        if np.isnan(sample) or sample == 0:
            sample = avg
        avg = (1 - alpha) * avg + alpha * sample
        avg_signal.append(avg)
    return np.array(avg_signal)

def train():
    x = np.random.rand(3000)
    y = run_avg(x)
    x = np.reshape(x, (-1, 1, 1))
    y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))
    
    # SimpleRNN model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype='float32'))
    model.add(keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, stateful=True, activation=None, name='rnn_layer_1'))
    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1), loss='mse')
    model.summary()
    
    print(model.get_layer('rnn_layer_1').get_weights())
    model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=1, epochs=10, shuffle=False)
    print(model.get_layer('rnn_layer_1').get_weights())

train()
```

But if we run the same using Native Keras, we get the error shown below:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("input_1_1:0", shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

If we replace the below line of code

```
model.add(Input(batch_shape=(1, 1, 1), dtype='float32'))
```

with the code below,

```
model.add(Dense(32, batch_input_shape=(1,1,1), dtype='float32'))
```

even the `model` with Keras implementation converges almost similar to TF Keras implementation.

You can refer the below links if you want to understand the difference in implementation from code perspective, in both the cases:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1364-L1375

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1082-L1091